# Utility Jar using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Created a custom jar using spring boot and this is using for CRUD operations on a database table.The purpose is  used to make this a utility jar, so that other services or applications can use this jar for any operations on that table. Following are the steps I followed:

1). Added this jar entry in pom.xml of a REST SERVICE and build got successfully. 
2). Autowired the service class of Utility jar inside the controller of REST SERVICE.

But when I started the REST SERVICE (service is developed on spring boot), I got the  error as 'the ****controller can require a bean of type *****serviceUtility. Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration'. But I am not able to see any configuration class inside the rest service and it is using application.yml for datasource related things. I am new to Spring and Spring Boot. Could any one guide me  how to configure the utility jar in external services.

Comment: can you show us a bit of code in order to help you out?

Comment: reasonable question , why -1 ?

Comment: @Vineeth you got your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell without source code, but Spring Boot jars do not by default work as utility jars. The packaging is different. To get a Spring Boot jar to work as a utility jar within another project, you'll want to configure the build plugin like this :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Which is described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot , by default , the utility jar will not move all its dependencies . 
You can add all the dependencies in the pom.xml for the Rest service .
Else you end up packaging some core modules twice increasing the size of your jar .